# Text field string is cut out in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I know that string type in c# can hold a long string so why when I'm passing the text from an asp.net form, in that string variable, the text is actually cut.

When I traced through the code I can see in the text visualizer that the entire long string is there but after running through the code I can see this string variable data cut in half in MySQL database. the column size in MySQL is TEXT which can hold up to four GB.

So I was wondering if anyone know what's going with this string truncating.

Comment: Can you show the code that is actually storing the data to your database?

Comment: Can you trace the SQL that was sent to the Mysql?

Comment: So you are using LONGTEXT since your limit is 4 GB?

Answer (score 3):

TEXT has a Max of 65,535 characters. If your content exceeds 64K bytes it possible you are exceeding the limit of the field characters.

To test this out you can change your field type to MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT

Answer (score 1):

According to MySQL dosc TEXT field holds up to L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16. -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

If one char is taking 2 bytes then max size is ~32.7k chars.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/

> TEXT data types are also able to store much more data than VARCHAR and
>   CHAR text types so TEXT types are what you need to use when storing
>   web page or similar content in a database.
>
> The maximum amount of data that can be stored in each data type is as
>   follows:
>
> TINYTEXT  256 bytes
>
> TEXT  65,535 bytes    ~64kb
>
> MEDIUMTEXT     16,777,215 bytes   ~16MB
>
> LONGTEXT  4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB
>
> In most circumstances
>   the TEXT type is probably sufficient, but if you are coding a content
>   management system it's probably best to use the MEDIUMTEXT type for
>   longer pages to ensure there are no issues with data size limits.

UPDATE: SqlParameter.Size (same is for MySQL I assume) can cut the string content before sending it to the DB.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size.aspx

> For output parameters with a variable length type (nvarchar, for
>   example), the size of the parameter defines the size of the buffer
>   holding the output parameter. The output parameter can be truncated to
>   a size specified with Size. For character types, the size specified
>   with Size is in characters.
>
> If not explicitly set, the size is inferred from the actual size of
>   the specified parameter value.

So remove the code that sets Size parameter of the ADO.NET parameter or try setting it to int.Max value.

Comment: even I changed the type of my column in the table from TEXT to Mediumtext, data still got cut. 
try to paste the code here but was kind of too long so i'm just gonna the actual line code:
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("?review_text", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.String));
 cmd.Parameters["?review_text"].Value = oReview.review_text;

Comment: make a breakpoint before the the execution of the INSERT. Look at the parameter that carries the text data. Does it have a size property set on it ? What the value of parameter.Size is ? If the Size is too low it can cut your string before sending to DB.

Comment: yes it works fine with smaller string content. But isn't it String type in C# be able to handle string length up to 2,147,483,647?? 
I just trace throught this variable like you suggested and display a length of 1010 only.

Comment: It's not String type that causes problems. If ADO.NET parameter has a defined size it will cut the string before sending it to the database.  I updated my answer.